# How to make JpaRepository only save the IDs that do not yet exist?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

Given a table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    some_id      BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    timestamp    TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL
);
```

An entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mytable")
class Thing(
        @Id
        var some_id: Long,
        var timestamp = ZonedDateTime.now()
)
```

A repository:

```
interface MyRepo : JpaRepository<Thing, Long>
```

And this loop:

```
val myRepo: MyRepo

while (True) {
    val some_id: Long = ComesFromSomewhere()
    if (myRepo.findById(some_id) == null) {
        myRepo.save(Thing(some_id))
    }
}
```

The intention is to only store a timestamp for an ID the first time this ID occurs.

The code above works, but results in over 100 `save` transactions per second in my use case, which puts heavy load on the DB. So I'd like to optimize, accumulate a batch of `Thing`s and then use something like `saveAll` to have everything in one transaction.

Just using `saveAll` however would also overwrite the timestamps of the IDs already present in the table, which is not intended.

How can this be solved, ideally without too much low-level code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the above loop within a @Transactional method, you should have only 1 transaction - with lots of INSERT-s and SELECT-s, of course, but 1 transaction. This would relieve the burden on the DB.

Also, save() is the proper method to call in this case. There's also a method called saveAndFlush() which is the opposite of what you want.

You could also limit the number of SELECTs by doing repo.findAllById() instead of lots of findById().